# c#.net how to get a HtmlGenricControll to show a RadioButtonList item

Tags: c#, radiobuttonlist, htmlgenericcontrol

I have a HtmlGenericController and to this I want to add RadioButtons. My radiobuttons come from a RadioButtonList an hence the objects are Listitems. How do I get my genericcontroller to show the radiobuttons?

This is my code

```
private HtmlGenericControl generateCells(String domainName)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            HtmlGenericControl dName = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            dName.InnerHtml = domainName;

            RadioButtonList radioList = new RadioButtonList();
            radioList.ID = "radio_" + domainName;
            radioList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;


            ListItem sunriseA = new ListItem();
            sunriseA.Value = Price_Types.SUNRISE_ONE.ToString();
            //sunriseA.Text = Price_Types.SUNRISE_ONE.ToString(); 
            sunriseA.Text = "";
            radioList.Items.Add(sunriseA);


            ListItem sunriseB = new ListItem();
            sunriseB.Value = Price_Types.SUNRISE_TWO.ToString();
            //sunriseB.Text = Price_Types.SUNRISE_TWO.ToString();
            sunriseB.Text = "";
            radioList.Items.Add(sunriseB);

            ListItem landrush = new ListItem();
            landrush.Value = Price_Types.LANDRUSH.ToString();
            //landrush.Text = Price_Types.LANDRUSH.ToString();
            landrush.Text = "";
            radioList.Items.Add(landrush);

            ListItem general = new ListItem();
            general.Value = Price_Types.GENERAL.ToString();
            //general.Text = Price_Types.GENERAL.ToString();
            general.Text = "";
            radioList.Items.Add(general);

            container.Controls.Add(dName);

            foreach (ListItem item in radioList.Items)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                span.InnerHtml = item;//what to put here??
                container.Controls.Add(span);
            }


            return container;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var radioButton = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
radioButton.Attributes["type"] = "radio";
radioButton.Attributes["name"] = "groupName";
radioButton.Attributes["value"] = "buttonValue";
```

That will only render the round radiobutton itself, though. To add a label, you'll have to render for example a `span` besides it. Or, IIRC, render a `label` field with the `for` attribute set to the ID of the radiobutton, so clicking the label will automatically click the button too.

Comment: Okej this sounds good, how will I find a groupname on postback whne I whant to "save" the selected radios? I have like 15-20 groups.